# Android NavigationView (material support lib) doesn't interact with the status bar properly

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design, android-design-library

I'm following the example from [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) to integrate the new Material Design Support library's [NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) into my app.

My general layout looks like this:

activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- main content -->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        .. />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

themes.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" extends "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```

MyActivity.java

```
onCreate(..) {
    ..
    // This color can be different depending on some conditions.
    DrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackground(color);
}
```

However, I keep getting a grey status bar, and the `NavigationView` does not draw under the status bar. I think the grey status bar is because I didn't define a custom `colorPrimaryDark` attr in the theme. However, I would assume `DrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackground` would override and set the status bar color. I can't find much documentation on the new `NavigationView`. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your `NavigationView` has `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` too?

Comment: I tried adding the attr on `NavigationView` but it didn't have any effect. The status bar just stays grey and non-transparent. It's almost as if `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` isn't doing anything because `DrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackground` isn't changing the status bar color...

Comment: `DrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackground(color)` should be throwing a `NotFoundException`. You should instead use `DrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color)`. Or is that just a mistake in the question?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. That was pseudocode/generalization in the question. I finally figured out my problem :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigh, I figured out my problem. There was some weird abstraction that we use to add a debug drawer on the right-hand side. As a result, the overall view hierarchy actually looks like this

```
<DrawerLayout id="debug">

    <LinearLayout id="debug_drawer" />

    <DrawerLayout id="nav_drawer" fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <NavigationView .... />

    </DrawerLayout>

</DrawerLayout>
```

So I was calling `DrawerLayout.setStatusBarColor` on the wrong drawer and setting `fitsSystemWindows` on the wrong drawer. As a result, the window never interacts with the status bar :(

Answer (score 7):

Add your styles for API 21+ in values-v21/themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In activity.xml, try setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on your `NavigationView` (in addition to the `DrawerLayout`).

Comment: I know it's bad style, but it doesn't matter because on pre-21 versions unrecognized attribute names will simply be ignored. So moving the styles to -v21 doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 4):

For every one struggling with this, your layout file should be something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    ...

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You have to include

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

in the DrawerLayout and in the NavigationView.